# msdeploy skip for exact-name folders

Tags: msdeploy, skip

. .

Here's the deal: I'm trying to use msdeploy to upload files.  I have a folder in my root called Search that I want it to skip.

So, I wrote a skip directive like this:

```
-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="Search"
```

The good news: it skips the Search folder like I want it to.

The bad news: it also skips any folder with "Search" in the name (example: "Research"), which I *don't* want it to do.  (Also, the "Research" folder being skipped is not off the web root, which raises a concern about controlling what folder locations are skipped.)

I tried a couple of variations, including these:

```
-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="\Search"
-skip:Directory="Search"
-skip:Directory="\Search"
```

No dice.  It's still skipping anything named "Research."

I tried looking up msdeploy syntax, and couldn't find anything that helps me.

Any thoughts from the peanut gallery?

Thanks!

Comment: Got it figured out.  I didn't realize that I was dealing with regular expressions.  I rewrote "Search" as "\\Search$".  Works like a champ!

Comment: Ray, add that as an answer, and then accept the answer.

Comment: Yeah, tried to yesterday, and it wouldn't let me do it -- something about an 8 hour limit before I could answer my own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it figured out.  For the benefit for anyone else who might be looking for an answer to this . . .

I didn't realize that I was dealing with regular expressions.  I rewrote "Search" as "\\Search$"